# CentOS - how do I check if "Development Tools" is installed?

Tags: centos7

I installed "Development Tools" with yum (`yum group install "Development Tools") and wanted to check it's installed. However, if I re-run the group install command I get:

```
Maybe run: yum groups mark install (see man yum)
No packages in any requested group available to install or update.
```

so I assume the group has installed. However is there a way to check? E.g. listing the packages so I can tick a few off.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Working_with_Package_Groups.html

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `yum grouplist` command e.g.

```
yum grouplist Dev* installed  ...
Installed Groups:
   Development tools
Done
```